# C++11 thread wrapper function

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I'd like to have a wrapper thread function, i.e. a function executed by a thread which does some extra stuff, and then calls the user function.

```
template<class F, class... Args>
void wrapper(F&& user_function, Args&&... args) {
  // do some extra stuff
  user_function(args); // maybe I need to forward args
  // do some extra stuff
}
```

Ok, this could be a nice wrapper, so I need a manager that uses this wrapper function and allows the user to spawn his own threads:

```
class ThreadManager {
public:

  template<class F, class... Args>
  std::thread newThread(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    return std::thread(thread_wrapper<F,Args...>, std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }

};
```

this way the thread manager *SHOULD* spawn a thread that uses the wrapper function which, in turn, does its extra work and calls the user function.

But the compiler now says: **Attempt to use a deleted function.**

The error is in the thread header:

```
template <class _Fp, class ..._Args, size_t ..._Indices>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
void
__thread_execute(tuple<_Fp, _Args...>& __t, __tuple_indices<_Indices...>)
{
    __invoke(_VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<0>(__t)), _VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<_Indices>(__t))...);
}
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

[edit]

Using test:

```
void foo(int i) {
  std::cout << "foo: " << i << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  ThreadManager mgr;
  auto t = mgr.newThread(foo, 10);
  t.detach();

  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));

  return 0;
}
```

I'm using Xcode 7.1 with LLVM compiler, but fails on FreeBSD clang 3.3 too.

The Xcode error is:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:337:5: error: attempt to use a deleted function
    __invoke(_VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<0>(__t)), _VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<_Indices>(__t))...);
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:347:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__thread_execute' requested here
    __thread_execute(*__p, _Index());
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:359:42: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__thread_proxy >' requested here
    int __ec = pthread_create(&__t_, 0, &__thread_proxy<_Gp>, __p.get());

Comment: post the exact error. What compiler and version do you use?

Comment: please post a [MCVE], I can't reproduce here: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/V2DCrfEgtvpjwWX7

Comment: your example on melpon.org fails if you use a normal function instead of a functor...

Comment: Note that explicitly using `thread_wrapper<F, Args...>` will turn your perfect forwarding `F&&` and `Args&&` parameters into actual rvalue reference parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is causing the "Attempt to use a deleted function" in your example, I get other errors related to `std::thread`'s bind mechanism.

It appears the way you are spelling out the template arguments for `thread_wrapper` is not playing nice with `std::thread`'s constructor - in particular when it uses a simplified `std::bind` internally. The mix of perfectly forwarded function types and `std::decay`ed function pointers seems to upset `std::result_of`.

we can make it work by applying some `std::decay` in `newThread` ourselves:

```
return std::thread( thread_wrapper<typename std::decay<F>::type,
                                   typename std::decay<Args>::type...>,
                    std::forward<F>(f), 
                    std::forward<Args>(args)... );
```

...but to be honest I'm not entirely sure *why* that works.

Alternatively, with some indirection and more forwarding, we can avoid having to spell out the template arguments.
We just need a functor that forwards to `thread_wrapper` (or a polymorphic lambda in C++14):

```
struct wrapper_helper {
    template<class F, class... Args>
    void operator()(F&& f, Args&&... args) const {
        thread_wrapper(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

And use it in `newThread`:

```
return std::thread(wrapper_helper{}, std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

Here's the full example showing arguments passed by value, reference and rvalue reference working as intended: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b75d5a264f583237

Note: For move-only types like `std::unique_ptr`, you will definitely want to forward `args...` in `thread_wrapper`.

Comment: Nice, seems working fine, but fails if trying to pass a unique_ptr
`std::unique_ptr<int> p{new int(10)};
mgr.newThread(my_function, std::move(p)); // fails
mgr.newThread(my_function, std::unique_ptr<int>{new int(10)}); // fails`

Comment: @AntonelloSeprano I would expect this if you didn't change `thread_ wrapper` to also forward the arguments - in which case it would attempt to copy the `unique_ptr` argument, which it cannot. [Works on my compiler if I do forward](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ddc16dbaf9042cf)

Comment: Yes, I didn't forward args in thread_wrapper, but now (with forwarding) stops working with normal vars: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a8c80b265c915ff

Comment: @AntonelloSeprano I was able to dig myself out of it by wrapping wrapper in a generic forwarding lambda before passing it to std::thread's constructor: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fae52fcdaa522b8e

Comment: works like a charm, but it is not C++11. Not a problem, of course :) Can I add another +1? :D
I set your answed as 'valid', please edit your answer adding your last suggest :)